# issues with uploading files to a root folder in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to this asp.net mvc since I used to work with webforms before. I have a project on hand that needs to upload a file to a root server folder.

I have a root folder in my solution named "Photos" and everytime I save my files it just leaves the folder empty but I was able to save the filename of the file into my database.

I used an html file upload control   `**<input type="file" id="Photos" name="Photos" title="Upload a Photo" />**` . How do I save the actual file into the root folder named "Photos"?

For you to understand further, I'm gonna give u my codes. Here are the following...Thanks

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ProfileModel user)
{
    // var fileimage = Request.Files[0];
    HttpFileCollectionBase hpf = Request.Files;
    HttpPostedFileBase file = hpf[0];
    string fname = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName.ToString());

    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        file.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Photos/") + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName.ToString())));
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        var addnewrec = new ProfTab()
        {
            ID = user.ID,
            Name = user.Name,
            Address = user.Address,
            Age = Convert.ToInt32(user.Age),
            Occupation = user.Occupation,
            Nationality = user.Nationality,
            // Photos=item.Photos 
            Photos = fname
        };
        repository.ProfTabs.Add(addnewrec);
        repository.SaveChanges();
        //   _repository.InsertRecord(user);                    
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

    }

    return View(user);
}
```

Create View

```
 @model MyFirstMVCApp.Models.ProfileModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>ProfileModel</legend>
        <div style="float:left; margin-right:20px;width:49%">
         <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
        </div>
  </div>

     <div style="float:right;width:48%">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Occupation)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Occupation)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Occupation)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nationality)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nationality)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nationality)
        </div>
         <label for="uploadphoto">Select a file:</label>
         <input type="file" id="Photos" name="Photos" title="Upload a Photo" />

  </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create"  />
             @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Your code looks OK, so it's probably an authorization issue. The file length could also be a problem (default 4MB max).

Comment: Can you show us some more HTML? Specifically your whole <form>

Comment: but I already specified the httpruntime on the web.config like this  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="2097151" requestLengthDiskThreshold="80" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100" enableKernelOutputCache="true" enableVersionHeader="true" requireRootedSaveAsPath="true" enable="true" delayNotificationTimeout="5" waitChangeNotification="0" maxWaitChangeNotification="0" enableHeaderChecking="true" sendCacheControlHeader="true" apartmentThreading="false"/>

Comment: @Tobias I just updated my post including my view. Please check... Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with the debugger? Is the file null, or does it actually reach the SaveAs method?

Comment: I could hardly identify in the developer tool's debugger if it's returning null value but I'm wondering whey it was able to capture the filename and save it into my database but unable to save the actual file to the root folder when they're referencing the same fileupload control in html.